# write a function for copying two strings

Tags: c, string

this code is not printing the copied value of two strings given that are target and source been created above  then a function is created that is stringcopy .

```
#include <stdio.h>

int stringcopy(char *target, char *source) {
    char *start = target;

    while (*target != '\0') { // this means while target is not equal to 0 that is null charecter
        *target = *source;
        target++;
        source++;
    }

    *target ='\0';
    return *start;
}

int main() {
    char source[34] = "Harry";
    char target[34];

    char copy = stringcopy(target, source);
    printf("%s", copy);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that with post-increment behavior, you can write: `*target++ = *source++;`

Comment: Suggestion: Make that `int stringcopy(char *target, const char *source)` since you are not supposed to change anything in `source`.

Comment: `return *start;` That returns a single character. Return type of that functions is `int`. Why not `char *`? Also when you call it, you seem to expect a pointer to a string: `printf("%s", copy);` while you only have a single `char`. Your compiler should have printed a few warnings.

Answer (score 3):

`*target != '\0'` but `*target` is uninitialized. You mean `*source != '\0'`.

Next problem: `int stringcopy` should be `char *stringcopy`. Your code will appear to work on a 32 bit platform otherwise, but it will blow up x64. You need to return the correct type.

Third problem: `char copy =` ; should be `char *copy =` ; I'm guessing you got here by arbitrarily mutating the code to get it to compile due to the second problem.

Forth problem: `return *start;` should be `return start;`. Thanks to [Gerhardh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782754/gerhardh) for catching it.

Comment: It will also not work on 32 bit platforms as long as the return value is only the first character instead its address. ;)

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/169KMErM9) with fixes for the problems mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Who is responsible for having enough room in `target` for the `source`? Or does anyone care?

Comment: @VladFeinstein: Caller. OP clearly has an assignment to implement `strcpy`.